# Reading a Spark RDD (created from HBase Table) in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

We have created a SparkRDD from a HBase table and now are wanting to access its elements. Here is what we have done 
1. Created RDD
`var hBaseRDD2 = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])`

2. taking first entry by this : `val type2 = hBaseRDD2.take(1)`
3. The output of `(hBaseRDD2.take(1).foreach(println))` is

   (31,keyvalues={1/PubEntity:Abstract/1476537886382/Put/vlen=9/mvcc=0, 1/PubEntity:Affiliations/1476537886382/Put/vlen=2/mvcc=0, 1/PubEntity:Article_Title/1476537886382/Put/vlen=64/mvcc=0, 1/PubEntity:Author/1476537886382/Put/vlen=497/mvcc=0, 1/PubEntity:Journal_Title/1476537886382/Put/vlen=20/mvcc=0, 1/PubEntity:PMID/1476537886382/Put/vlen=1/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:Countries/1476537886382/Put/vlen=2/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:Created_At/1476537886382/Put/vlen=11/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:DOI/1476537886382/Put/vlen=9/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:Date_Created/1476537886382/Put/vlen=8/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:ISO_Abbreviation/1476537886382/Put/vlen=11/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:ISSN/1476537886382/Put/vlen=9/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:Pub_Date/1476537886382/Put/vlen=12/mvcc=0, 1/PubRemaining:Year/1476537886382/Put/vlen=4/mvcc=0})
4. printing type of "type2" by `println(type2.getClass)` which outputs

   class [Lscala.Tuple2;
5. SInce it shows that type2 is tuple i tried doing this

   println(type2._1)
   for which it outputs an error as this :

   error: value _1 is not a member of Array[(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result)]

How can read say for example "PubEntity:Article_Title" from the entries. See a sample of the entry in the output of #3 above. Thanks

Comment: [Lscala.Tuple2 means an array of Tuple2. Actually with the generic type it is Array[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)]. Each element in the array corresponds to a single row with (K,V) as the tuple [since we could have used take(10) too]. If you are using an IDE, the type info of any Scala variable will be available directly instead of logging and inferring the same [For e.g. in Idea it is Alt+=]

Comment: @balaudt is  correct ! your rdd is type of [ImmutableBytesWritable, Result] which you can map to only Bytes.toString(Result.getValue(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier)) to get your expected result.